# Not able to send email to TOList, CC is working fine using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, email

I am using spring email and MIME Message to send an email. I am not able to send an email to the alias when I am putting the alias in TO list. If I put the same alias in CC list then my code is working fine. I am not able to understand what is wrong in that. Please give your inputs.

```
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    public void sendMail(String User, String login, String subject, String msg)
            throws FileNotFoundException, MessagingException {
        // creating message
        log.info("In Email now");

        String to = null, sender = null, Cc = null;
        try {

            sender = EXTUtilClass.getProperty(
                    EXTConstants.BATCH_EMAIL_FROM_LIST,
                    EXTConstants.EXT_CONFIG_PROPERTIES);

            to = EXTUtilClass.getProperty(EXTConstants.BATCH_EMAIL_TO_LIST,
                    EXTConstants.EXT_CONFIG_PROPERTIES);

            Cc = User;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            log.error("Error in email with error:" + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error in email with error:" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // sending message
        MimeMessage MIMEmessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        //MimeMessageHelper helper = null;
        try {
            //helper = new MimeMessageHelper(MIMEmessage, true);
            //helper.setFrom(sender);
            // helper.setTo(message.getTo());
            /*to.replaceAll( ";", ","); 
            helper.getMimeMessage().setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));

            Cc.replaceAll(";", ",");
            helper.getMimeMessage().setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Cc));

            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText(msg, true);*/

            MIMEmessage.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse( sender ));
            to = to.replaceAll( ";", ",");  
            MIMEmessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));

            Cc = Cc.replaceAll(";", ",");
            MIMEmessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,
                    InternetAddress.parse(Cc));

            MIMEmessage.setSubject(subject);
            MIMEmessage.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            //MIMEmessage.setText(msg);


        } catch (MessagingException e) {

            MIMEmessage.setSubject(subject);
            StringBuilder WrongEmailmsg = new StringBuilder(msg);
            WrongEmailmsg.insert(msg.indexOf("Note"),
                    "<b>Error: Email address of " + login
                            + " is not correct.</b><br><br>");
            MIMEmessage.setText(msg);

            log.info("Error in email with error:" + e.getMessage());
            log.error("Error in email with error:" + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Error in email with error:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        mailSender.send(MIMEmessage);

        log.info("Email sent successfully.");
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");

    }
```

XMl file :

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="#{configProperties['host.name']}" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
              <props>
                    <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false</prop>
                    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>

              </props>
        </property>
     </bean>
```

For example in cc if I am using group_mails.gmail.com and group_mails contains "xyz.gmail.com.abc.gmail.com". Then this code works fine for me but if i am using `to = group_mails.com` then this code doesn't work. I am not able to find where I am making mistake.

Comment: There is no problem in the code. It was a host problem.